# How to vlookup value and get value to the right

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I vlookup for a value and get value to the right?

Dataframe one:

```
   AD1   AF   GG 
0  DDA   4    2   
1  AA    1    2
```

Dataframe two:

```
    AD   FA  HH   
0   DDA  3   4
1   DD   3   4
```

Desired (dataframe 3):

```
    AD   FA
0   DDA  3      
1   DD  NaN
```

For:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AD', 'FA'])
WE = df3.merge(df1, on='AD1', how='left')
df1['FA']=WE
#WE = df2.AD=np.where(df2.AD.isin(df1.AD1),df2.AD,np.nan)
```

I get `KeyError: 'AD'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df3 = df2[['AD', 'FA']].copy()
df3.FA=np.where(df2.AD.isin(df1.AD1),df3.FA,np.nan)
print (df3)
    AD   FA
0  DDA  3.0
1   DD  NaN
```

EDIT:

```
print (df1)
       EW       WE      DA     dd  AA
0  cheese     fdwa  waddcv   21.0 NaN
1  cheese  dwadwad    dwad  231.0 NaN
2  cheese      dwa  waddcv    3.0 NaN

print (df2)
       AD   FA     BA  DA    daw
0  cheese  1.0  300.0   T      T
1  dwadaw  3.0  400.0  21  31232
```

---

```
#remove duplicates in EW and merge by different columns
df3 = df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates('EW')[['EW']], left_on='AD', right_on='EW', how='left')
df3.FA=np.where(df2.AD.isin(df1.EW),df3.FA,np.nan)
df3 = df3[['AD','FA']]
print (df3)
       AD   FA
0  cheese  1.0
1  dwadaw  NaN
```

EDIT1:

```
df3 = df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.EW)]
df3 = df3[['AD','FA']]
print (df3)
       AD   FA
0  cheese  1.0
```

Detail:

```
print (df2.AD.isin(df1.EW))
0     True
1    False
Name: AD, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if understand. Why is necessary delete `df3` ? Can you explain more?

Comment: Hmm sorry this is confusing me a little.  https://pastebin.com/YFP2mUVs I'm not able to get it working with this dataset

Comment: OK, there is first problem there is no match `cheese` vs `Cheese`, need same values. It is typo or real data?

Comment: Uh that makes sense.  Why is it displaying 4, 5 though can that be removed at all?

Comment: It is second problem, give me a minute.

Comment: Maybe the copying is causing the issues.

Comment: How strange, same result keeps happening for me

Comment: Hmmm, so maybe not understand it well, give me a sec, I have an idea

Comment: If need filter values of df2 by df1 column EW there is another solution.

Comment: I think it's still doing it.  I will retry.

Comment: There is a bit different it, because filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), there is no `np.where`

Comment: I should probably write this as new question as that did work for the example given.  This seems a bit more complicated I guess.

Comment: Yes, it is good idea. Please add sample data, desired out put and what you try (some code).